# boxes are in the same order in a column

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes, columns

I want to draw boxes as in the picture, but the same order. So i create a table and i add the boxes in the columns of the table but it did not work. Also, I do not want that the texts on the arrows intertwine with the box (e.g. as in 3rd box).

[image]

Here is my code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{flowchart}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\newcommand{\GCinp}{\ensuremath{\mathsf{GC}_I}}
\newcommand{\GCout}{\ensuremath{\mathsf{GC}_O}}
\newcommand{\GCnorm}{\ensuremath{\mathsf{GC}_N}}
\newcommand{\GC}{\ensuremath{\mathsf{GC}}}
%algorithms

\newcommand{\genEqCons}{\texttt{GenEqConst}} 
\newcommand{\genEqNum}{\texttt{GenEqNumbers}}
\newcommand{\genKeys}{\texttt{GenKeys}}
\newcommand{\comInput}{\texttt{CommitInput}} 
\newcommand{\genOutput}{\texttt{GenOutputNums}}
\newcommand{\genGC}{\texttt{ConstructGC}}
\newcommand{\getEqNum}{\texttt{GetEqNumbers}}

%sets
\newcommand{\seteconst}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{E}}}
\newcommand{\setenum}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{M}}}
\newcommand{\setirand}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{U}}}
\newcommand{\setKeys}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{K}}}
\newcommand{\setpartdecom}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{R}}}
\newcommand{\setinpCom}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{D}}}
\newcommand{\setrandRow}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{P}}}
\newcommand{\setcomRandRow}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{S}}}
\newcommand{\setoutput}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{O}}}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}

\begin{center}
    \begin{scriptsize}
        \begin{tabular}{R{5cm} C{5cm} L{5cm}} 

            &\textbf{S2PC phase} &\\

        $ \{m_{i,x_i}\}_{i = 1} ^\ell \leftarrow $ \getEqNum($x, \setenum_a$)   & $\xrightarrow[\hspace{4cm}]{\GC_a, \{m_{i,x_i}\}_{i = 1} ^\ell , \setinpCom,\setcomRandRow} $ & \\
            & $\xleftarrow[\hspace{4cm}]{\GC_b, \{m_{i,y_i}\}_{i = 1} ^\ell , \setinpCom',\setcomRandRow'} $ & $ \{m'_{i,y_i}\}_{i = 1} ^\ell \leftarrow $ \getEqNum($y, \setenum'_b$) \\

            & \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, thick, scale = 0.6]

            \node (A) at (0,0) [draw, process, text width=1.5cm, minimum height=1cm, align=flush center] 
            {Check Correctness};

            \coordinate (B) at (4,0.54);

            \coordinate (C)  at (4,-0.48);

            \coordinate (D) at (-4,0);

            \coordinate (E) at (-4,0);


            \draw[->] (D) -- node[above] {\setcomRandRow,\setirand} (A);
            \draw[->] (A.-18) -- node[below]{0/1}(C);
            \draw[->] (B)  -- node[above] {\setinpCom,\setcomRandRow} (A.20);


            \end{tikzpicture}& \\

            & \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, thick, scale = 0.6]

            \node (A) at (0,0) [draw, process, text width=1.5cm, minimum height=1cm, align=flush center] 
            {Check Correctness};

            \coordinate (B) at (4,0.0);

            \coordinate (C)  at (4,0);

            \coordinate (D) at (-4,0.54);

            \coordinate (E) at (-4,-0.6);


            \draw[->] (A.203) -- node[above] {0/1} (E);
            \draw[->] (B) -- node[below]{\setcomRandRow',\setirand'}(A);
            \draw[->] (D)  -- node[above] {\setinpCom',\setcomRandRow'} (A.160);


            \end{tikzpicture}& \\


            & \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, thick, scale = 0.6]

            \node (A) at (0,0) [draw, process, text width=1.5cm, minimum height=1cm, align=flush center] 
            {S2PC ($\GC_a$)};

                \coordinate (B) at (4,0.54);

                \coordinate (C)  at (4,-0.48);

                \coordinate (D) at (-4,0);

                \coordinate (E) at (-4,0);


                \draw[->] (D) -- node[above] {$ x $} (A);
                \draw[->] (A.-18) -- node[below]{\setoutput$ _a, \{m_{i,y_i}\}_{i=1}^\ell $}(C);
                \draw[->] (B)  -- node[above] {$ y $} (A.20);
                .160);


            \end{tikzpicture}& \\


            & \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, thick, scale = 0.6]

            \node (A) at (0,0) [draw, process, text width=1.5cm, minimum height=1cm, align=flush center] 
            {S2PC ($\GC_b$)};

        \coordinate (B) at (4,0.0);

        \coordinate (C)  at (4,0);

        \coordinate (D) at (-4,0.54);

        \coordinate (E) at (-4,-0.6);


        \draw[->] (A.203) -- node[below] {$ \setoutput'_b, \{m'_{i,x_i}\}_{i=1}^\ell$} (E);
        \draw[->] (B) -- node[below]{$ y $}(A);
        \draw[->] (D)  -- node[above] {$ x $} (A.160);

        \end{tikzpicture}& \\



        \end{tabular}
    \end{scriptsize}
\end{center}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you don't want to enlarge arrows, insert some value after `below` in `node[below=...]{}` for label in third box.

Comment: Please, would you mind to include a `complete` example: from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` and including all necessary packages and definitions. It simplifies helpers work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath}
%        \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,chains,positioning}% <-- added libraries
%        \usepackage{flowchart}

    \usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}
    \PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\newcommand{\GCinp}{\ensuremath{\mathsf{GC}_I}}
\newcommand{\GCout}{\ensuremath{\mathsf{GC}_O}}
\newcommand{\GCnorm}{\ensuremath{\mathsf{GC}_N}}
\newcommand{\GC}{\ensuremath{\mathsf{GC}}}
%algorithms

\newcommand{\genEqCons}{\texttt{GenEqConst}}
\newcommand{\genEqNum}{\texttt{GenEqNumbers}}
\newcommand{\genKeys}{\texttt{GenKeys}}
\newcommand{\comInput}{\texttt{CommitInput}}
\newcommand{\genOutput}{\texttt{GenOutputNums}}
\newcommand{\genGC}{\texttt{ConstructGC}}
\newcommand{\getEqNum}{\texttt{GetEqNumbers}}

%sets
\newcommand{\seteconst}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{E}}}
\newcommand{\setenum}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{M}}}
\newcommand{\setirand}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{U}}}
\newcommand{\setKeys}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{K}}}
\newcommand{\setpartdecom}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{R}}}
\newcommand{\setinpCom}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{D}}}
\newcommand{\setrandRow}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{P}}}
\newcommand{\setcomRandRow}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{S}}}
\newcommand{\setoutput}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{O}}}

%\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
%\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
%\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, thick,
node distance = 5mm and 24mm,
  start chain = going below,
   box/.style = {name=#1,
                 draw, align=flush center,
                 text width=22mm, minimum height=9mm, inner sep=1mm,
                 on chain},
     u/.style = {yshift=#1 mm}]
%--- 
\linespread{0.8}
%--- boxes
    \node[box=A] {Check Correctness};
%--- 
    \coordinate[left =of A] (Aleft);
    \coordinate[right=of A] (Aright);
\draw[->] (Aleft)               to node[above] {\setcomRandRow,\setirand} (A);
\draw[->] ([u=+2] A.east) 
    to node[above] {\setinpCom,\setcomRandRow}  ([u=+2] Aright);
\draw[->] ([u=-2] A.east) to node[below]  {0/1} ([u=-2] Aright);
%---
    \node[box=B]    {Check Correctness};
\draw[->] ([u=+2] Aleft |- B) to node[above] {0/1}  ([u=+2] B.west);
\draw[<-] ([u=-2] Aleft |- B) 
    to node[below]{\setcomRandRow',\setirand'}      ([u=-2] B.west);
\draw[->] (B) to node[above] {\setinpCom',\setcomRandRow'} (B -| Aright);
%---
    \node[box=C]    {S2PC ($\GC_a$)};
\draw[->] (Aleft |- C) to node[above] {$x$}     (C);
\draw[->] ([u=+2] C.east) to node[above] {$y$}  ([u=+2] C -| Aright);
\draw[->] ([u=-2] C.east) 
    to node[below] {\setoutput$_a,\{m_{i,y_i}\}_{i=1}^\ell $}   
                                                ([u=-2] C -| Aright);
%---
    \node[box=D]    {S2PC ($\GC_b$)};
\draw[->] ([u=+2] Aleft |- D.west) to node[above] {$x$}         ([u=+2] D.west);
\draw[<-] ([u=-2] Aleft |- D.west)
    to node[below] {$\setoutput'_b,\{m'_{i,x_i}\}_{i=1}^\ell$}  ([u=-2] D.west);
\draw[<-] (D)  to node[above] {$y$} (D -| Aright);
%--- top of picture
\node[align=center,above=of A] (E)
{
$\xrightarrow[\hspace{42mm}]
             {\GC_a,\{m_{i,x_i}\}_{i=1}^\ell,\setinpCom,\setcomRandRow}$\\
$\xleftarrow[\hspace{42mm}]
            {GC_b,\{m_{i,y_i}\}_{i = 1}^\ell,\setinpCom',\setcomRandRow'}$
};
\node[left =0mm of E]
    {$\{m_{i,x_i}\}_{i=1}^\ell\leftarrow\text{\getEqNum}(x,\setenum_a)$};
\node[right=0mm of E]
    {$\{m'_{i,x_i}\}_{i=1}^\ell\leftarrow\text{\getEqNum}(x,\setenum'_b)$};

\node[above=of E] (F) {\textbf{S2PC phase}};
            \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

As far as I understand provided picture, you can achieve it without tabular(x) environment. So I omit from your code all what is concern tabular environment. For picture composition I use additional TikZ libraries (chains, positioning).

[image]